Incenter $O_1$ of hexagon, the radical center $O$ and the centers of Appollonian circles are collinear
A circle $O_1$ is inscribed in a hexagon $ABCDEF$, whose diagonals $AD,BE,CF$ pass through a common point $O$.
Take equal lengths on the tangents: $PL =UV= RJ = QH = SY=TW$.
Draw circles $a, b, c$ tangent to opposite sides of the hexagon at the created points ($H,W$), ($J,V$) and ($L,Y$) respectively.
Draw circle $O_2$ externally tangent to all three circles $a,b,c$. (Problem of Apollonius)
Draw circle $O_3$ internally tangent to all three circles $a,b,c$.
How do you prove $O,O_1,O_2,O_3$ are collinear?


The concurring lines $AD,BE,CF$ coincide with the radical axes $ab, bc, ca$ resepectively, of the three circles taken in pairs. Thus $O$ coincides with the radical center of $a,b,c$.
Consider the line$$\ell:\quad\begin{vmatrix}1&r_1&(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2-r_1^2\\1&r_2&(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2-r_2^2\\1&r_3&(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2-r_3^2\end{vmatrix}=0$$where $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$ are the centers of $a,b,c$ and $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are the radii of $a,b,c$ respectively.
The third column of the determinant is the power of $(x,y)$ to the circles $a,b,c$.

When $(x,y)=O$, the radical center of $a,b,c$, then the power of $(x,y)$ to $a,b,c$ are equal, so the determinant is zero, so $O\in\ell$.

When $(x,y)=O_1$, the center of the inscribed circle of hexagon $ABCDEF$, denote its radius by $\rho$, denote $PL=UV=RJ=QH=SY=TW=d$, then the power of $(x,y)$ to $a$ is $(d-r_1)^2+\rho^2-r_1^2=d^2+\rho^2-2dr_1$, so the determinant is
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&r_1&d^2+\rho^2-2dr_1\\1&r_2&d^2+\rho^2-2dr_2\\1&r_3&d^2+\rho^2-2dr_3\end{vmatrix}=0$$
so $O_1\in\ell$.

When $(x,y)=O_2$, the center of external common tangential circle of $a,b,c$, denote its radius by $R$, then$$\begin{vmatrix}1&r_1&(R-r_1)^2-r_1^2\\1&r_2&(R-r_2)^2-r_2^2\\1&r_3&(R-r_3)^2-r_3^2\end{vmatrix}=0$$so $O_2\in\ell$.

When $(x,y)=O_3$, the center of internal common tangential circle of $a,b,c$, denote its radius by $r$, then$$\begin{vmatrix}1&r_1&(r+r_1)^2-r_1^2\\1&r_2&(r+r_2)^2-r_2^2\\1&r_3&(r+r_3)^2-r_3^2\end{vmatrix}=0$$so $O_3\in\ell$.
